# How can I cast an object to a different type which shares a common base class without explicitly declaring the type in the code?

Tags: c#

I have a base configuration class with multiple sub classes which I use to store a configuration. In the program, you can dynamically select a different type of configuration, but doing that clears the configuration options common to these configurations.

I have some configuration types:

```
class ConfigurationBase
class ConfigurationA : ConfigurationBase
class ConfigurationB : ConfigurationBase
```

They are stored in a configuration object:

```
public static ConfigurationBase configuration;
```

And I have a function which changes the configuration:

```
public static void ChangeConfiguration(Type configuration_type)
{
    configuration = (ConfigurationBase)Activator.CreateInstance(configuration_type);
}
```

I wanted to try something like this: but it's not valid c#:

```
public static void ChangeConfiguration(Type configuration_type)
{
    configuration = configuration as configuration_type;
}
```

How can I change the configuration type and keep the common attributes in the new configuration?

Comment: I"m pretty sure you'll have to clone the common attributes to a new object of the desired type. You could use composition instead of inheritance if this is a common need.

Comment: Why do configurations need to change _type_?

Comment: @sloopy: I still think this is kind of odd, but I added an answer that gives you the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Cannot test it right now, but</strike> This should give you the desired behavior:

```cs
public static void ChangeConfigType<T>() 
    where T: ConfigurationBase
{
    configuration = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(configuration));
}
```

UPDATE:
The deserialization ignores all the properties that the target type does not have and does not care about the ones the source does not have (they will have default values).

I didn't benchmark, but it certainly spares you the maintainance effort of n<sup>2</sup> "ChangeFromXtoY" methods.

I am also assuming, performance is not *that* critical here. I don't believe you are going to transform millions of configs a second, do you?

See it in Action: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/27hpob)

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ConfigBase cfg = new Config1 { Name = "Slim Shady", Num = 1 };
        cfg.Dump();
        cfg = ChangeConfig<Config2>(cfg);
        cfg.Dump();
    }
    
    public static ConfigBase ChangeConfig<TOutput>(ConfigBase input) 
        where TOutput: ConfigBase
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TOutput>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(input));
    }
}

public class ConfigBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Config1 : ConfigBase
{
    public int Num {get; set;}
}

public sealed class Config2 : ConfigBase
{
    public DateTime Dat {get; set;}
}
```

Output:

```
Dumping object(Config1)
 Name  : Slim Shady
 Num   : 1
Dumping object(Config2)
 Dat   : 01/01/0001
 Name  : Slim Shady
```

If you need or prefer a version taking a type argument instead of using Generics, that also works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pLjAFz

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ConfigBase cfg = new Config1 { Name = "Slim Shady", Num = 1 };
        cfg.Dump();
        cfg = ChangeConfig(cfg, typeof(Config2));
        cfg.Dump();
    }
    
    public static ConfigBase ChangeConfig(ConfigBase input, Type targetType)
    {
        return (ConfigBase)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonSerializer.Serialize(input), targetType);
    }
}
```

This has identical output as above. You might want to add a type check.

Disclaimer: I still think there must be a better solution *to your problem* (which I do not know enough about), but this is doing what you described in the question.

Comment: This is an excellent solution for me. Especially since I am using the same json serializer to save and load my configurations. As for the bigger problem, I'm not sure of any other way around needing different types of configurations. The program is used to monitor and control different industrial processes which require different parameters, some of which may be common to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to copy common properties in the base class:

```
public class ConfigurationBase{
public int CommonProperty { get; set; }
public void CopyTo(ConfigurationBase target)
{
    target.CommonProperty = this.CommonProperty;
}}
```

create a new configuration and copy common properties

```
public static void ChangeConfiguration(Type configuration_type){
var newConfig = (ConfigurationBase)Activator.CreateInstance(configuration_type);
configuration.CopyTo(newConfig);
configuration = newConfig;}
```

the CopyTo() copies common properties. The ChangeConfiguration() uses CopyTo() to keep the common property values.

Comment: Nice and simple. I'm hoping someone knows of a more esoteric solution which would not require writing and maintaining these functions for each class. There is currently 1 base class with 4 subclasses, but it will soon become 1 base class with many subclasses, and each subclass will have a few subclasses as well.

Comment: _"but it will soon become 1 base class with many subclasses, and each subclass will have a few subclasses as well."_ sounds like a bad idea, really.

Comment: "sounds like a bad idea, really." I'm not sure if I will need the common attributes to cross that second layer, but it's a possibility. For now, it will not. It sounds like a bad idea, but this software is very dynamic and will replace a suite of at least 10 applications (which all do a very similar thing) which are practically unmaintainable now.